# how to remove the duplicate item from the object in PHP?

Tags: php

here's the sample array

```
array(
       0 => blah object
          (
   [bagid] => 12345
   [userid] => 12345,
   and so on and so forth..
        )
    )
```

this is the output when I var_dump the $data object, if i loop it through 
foreach loop,it will print the bagid,userid,and etc....of the owner of the data..
now the question is, I only want to display 1 unique bagid coming from a user...
no matter how many bagid the user has, is that doable ?how?

Comment: So each `blah` object has a `bagid` and `userid` property and you have a list of `blah` objects?

Comment: [what have you tried? what you researched on your own?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice)

Comment: Arrays cannot have duplicate keys

Comment: the blah object is a database query result, and bagid,userid, are the properties , if e.g user 12345  has bagid = 1,2,3,4...i should i only display 1 ....... another scenario, at the frontpage of the site, i should be able to display 4 blah objects,providing that criteria i mentioned..

Comment: So bagid is a string containing comma separated values?

Answer (score 1):

use `array_unique`

```
<?php
$input = array("a" => "green", "red", "b" => "green", "blue", "red");
$result = array_unique($input);
print_r($result);
?>
```

output :

```
Array
(
[a] => green
[0] => red
[1] => blue
)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: the problem with the array_unique is that..an object cannot be converted to string, i cannot use that built-in function in php, am dealing with object and not just simple arrays

Comment: Array_unique removes duplicate values, in his particular example, if he applied it to blah object that would remove userid value

Comment: am getting this error Object of class blah could not be converted to string

Comment: @sasori you have to convert your object to array , because there is no inbuilt function for uniqueness og object values.